# connection timeout to smtp with python/openerp

Tags: python, email, odoo

when i add the correct config for outgoing email to my openerp server i always get a connection timeout problem:

```
2013-10-10 08:22:35,119 20541 INFO MyCompany werkzeug: 192.168.1.50 - - [10/Oct/2013 08:22:35] "POST /web/dataset/call_kw HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2013-10-10 08:22:35,191 20541 INFO MyCompany werkzeug: 192.168.1.50 - - [10/Oct/2013 08:22:35] "POST /web/menu/load_needaction HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2013-10-10 08:22:35,395 20541 INFO MyCompany werkzeug: 192.168.1.50 - - [10/Oct/2013 08:22:35] "POST /web/dataset/call_kw HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2013-10-10 08:22:35,405 20541 INFO ? werkzeug: 192.168.1.50 - - [10/Oct/2013 08:22:35] "GET /web/static/src/img/form_sheetbg.png HTTP/1.1" 304 -
2013-10-10 08:22:35,626 20541 INFO ? werkzeug: 192.168.1.50 - - [10/Oct/2013 08:22:35] "GET /web/static/src/img/icons/gtk-network.png HTTP/1.1" 304 -
2013-10-10 08:22:35,631 20541 INFO MyCompany werkzeug: 192.168.1.50 - - [10/Oct/2013 08:22:35] "POST /web/dataset/search_read HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2013-10-10 08:22:38,117 20541 ERROR MyCompany openerp.netsvc: Connection Test Failed!
Hier sehen Sie, was wir an Stelle dessen bekommen haben:
 110
Die Wartezeit für die Verbindung ist abgelaufen
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/netsvc.py", line 292, in dispatch_rpc
    result = ExportService.getService(service_name).dispatch(method, params)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/service/web_services.py", line 626, in dispatch
    res = fn(db, uid, *params)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 188, in execute_kw
    return self.execute(db, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw or {})
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 131, in wrapper
    return f(self, dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 197, in execute
    res = self.execute_cr(cr, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 185, in execute_cr
    return getattr(object, method)(cr, uid, *args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_mail_server.py", line 215, in test_smtp_connection
    raise osv.except_osv(_("Connection Test Failed!"), _("Here is what we got instead:\n %s") % tools.ustr(e))
except_osv: (u'Connection Test Failed!', u'Hier sehen Sie, was wir an Stelle dessen bekommen haben:\n 110\nDie Wartezeit f\xfcr die Verbindung ist abgelaufen')
```

Perhaps there is still something wrong with my routing, but the POP server works fine. Does anyone have an idea what there is wrong?

I also tried it with googlemail but without success :/
Thanks

Comment: when pop works fine it doesn't mean that outgoing mailserver should work fine. smtp could be a different server than pop. So check your smtp server name is correct (if you are under proxy check with the ip address). And if that's right check the username and password and if that username and pass didn't work out try another uname and pass of the same domain. Also put your configuration parameters here to understand better.

Comment: I used exactly the same parameters like in thunderbird. I am sure that this is no problem of the smtp parameters config. do you have any other idea?

Comment: pls put your configuration parameters.

Comment: smtp.gmail.com; port=465; SSL/TLS; myUserName@gmail.com; password=password

Comment: hmmm... yes. this is possible. The server is behind a Modem/Router

Comment: Just remove yourusername and password and click on test connection. see if your connection succeeds

Comment: Then use this ip 173.194.66.109 instead of smtp.gmail.com. It should work.

Comment: Unfortunately both of the changes had no effect.

Comment: I guess the port number of 465 is not opened for your ip. Try this 'telnet 173.194.66.109 465' in command line. If this is not able to connect then you need to contact your administrator and enable port 25 (smtp) 465 (secure smtp) for your ip.

Comment: Yes, connection via telnet is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out why the problem occoured. For some reason the delivering of the email is not working when the hostname on linux is not set correctly. After changing the /etc/hosts and /etc/hostname the sending of the email worked!

Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

If you are under a proxy. You should probably use something like this

[image]

First don't give the username and password to check that the smtp server name is correct and active. If this succeeds give the username and password and check again.

**Utility:** To find out the ip of a domain name i find this useful http://www.hcidata.info/host2ip.cgi

Cheers!!

Comment: for sure the username and password are not the original ones ;) And yes, i tried to ping the server (which works perfectly). Even the Router should be no problem for this. Do you have any other idea?

Comment: No not pinging, try to connect to that port using telnet. You should be able to connect if it's allowed for u.

Comment: Thunderbird can connect from the same machine. So i think this is no connection-issue. I'll try telnet anyway :)

Comment: yes, telnet works perfectly... even with smtp.gmail.com instead of the IP... address resolving works

Comment: Really strange!! Did u modify anything in the code? If possible try the same with a fresh instance. I don't have any other solution.

Comment: No i did not modify the code, but i have to if the probem persists. Other solutions could be: 1) create a local smtp proxy server 2) inject the outgiong smtp packages during sending 3) downgrade python (could be a python probl.) 4) modify the python code for sending 5) writing a own plugin for sending mails... anyway it seems that a simple solution is not possible. At first i try to generate a more specific output of the log files and analyzing the network packages for smtp.

Comment: aaah one idea is left: my log-file is 2 hours behind the current time.. is it possible that openerp has a wrong time? where can i check this? (the machine has a correct time)

Comment: MEZ (UTC +1) is correct. Timezone under Admin -> account settings is set to Europe/Berlin (which is correct)

Comment: That's correct. please refer my post here http://stackoverflow.com/a/19239134/1664788

Comment: ok, but does this have any influence on the timeout during smtp-sending?

Comment: It doesn't do anything with timeout error. It will help you understand better to see if the time is really wrong.

Comment: now i captured the smtp package transfer: the correct server brings the response: 220 SERVICE READY; Strange is: Src Port = 25, Dst Port: 37240 ????? what does this mean?

Comment: now i captured the smtp package transfer: the correct server brings the response: 220 SERVICE READY; When i try to send email through OpenERP there is only one package sent.. with thunderbird a few more (including the real sending). It seems to be a bug from OpenERP

Answer (score 0):

I think the error you got is because of the wrong credential, please make sure it's correct.
Please look at the screen shot hope it will help.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Atul, i already tried this. It is also no problem with the two-factor-authentication at google. my other smtp server wont work too. The timeout is also not the problem. I can send emails from the same machine through thunderbird without problems.

Comment: I have generated the same traceback in my local machine, using the wrong credential.